# How to use kde_kws parameters for seaborn.histplot()?

Tags: seaborn

I am trying to use sns.histplot() instead of sns.distplot() since I got the following message in colab:

> FutureWarning: `distplot` is a deprecated function and will be removed
> in a future version. Please adapt your code to use either `displot` (a
> figure-level function with similar flexibility) or `histplot` (an axes-level function for histograms).

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.histplot(df['tip'], kde=True, kde_kws={'fill' : True});
```

I got an error when passing `kde_kws` parameters inside `sns.histplot()`:

*TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill'*

Comment: It seems the `kde_kws` are only sent to the kde calculation (so, parameters such as `bw_method` for `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`) and not to `sns.kdeplot()`. A possible way to combine a histogram and a kde plot is `sns.histplot(df['tip'], stat='density'); sns.kdeplot(df['tip'], fill=True)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html?highlight=histplot#seaborn.histplot) `kde_kws=` is intended to pass arguments "that control the KDE computation, as in kdeplot()." It is not entirely explicit which arguments those are, but they seem to be the ones like `bw_method=` and `bw_adjust=` that change the way the KDE is computed, rather than displayed. If you want to change the appearance of the KDE plot, the you can use `line_kws=`, but, as the name implies, the KDE is represented only by a line and therefore cannot be filled.

If you want both a histogram and a filled KDE, you need to combine `histplot()` and `kdeplot()` on the same axes

```
sns.histplot(df['tip'], stat='density')
sns.kdeplot(df['tip'], fill=True)
```

Comment: @ DizietAsahi, thanks for highlighting *computations*. From [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html?highlight=histplot#seaborn.histplot): _Parameters that control the KDE *computation*, as in kdeplot()_